# Is it better to write temporaries into their own new variable?

Tags: c++, variables, copy

I come across this situation a lot, where you have a temp variable whose value needs to be modified, *and you don't need access to the old value* after modification.

```
// Find out if the jello will be jiggly
// at a certain time
bool IsJiggly( JelloType jello, float time )
{
    // JelloType has some weird overloads..
    jello = jello + time ; // I don't need the unrefrigerated jello,
    // _so I overwrite jello_..

    return jello.jiggles() ;
}

bool IsJiggly( JelloType jello, float time )
{
    JelloType jello2 = jello + time ; // I don't need the unrefrigerated jello,
    // but I create a new variable anyway, 
    return jello2.jiggles() ;
}
```

(I realize the above example is somewhat contrived, ie `JelloType` should have a member function `operator+=` .. but the situation is not!)

So, the question is:  **_In C++, is it better, performance wise, to *overwrite* the variable, or just create a new one and use that?_**

Comment: In practice, you wouldn't notice the difference. In both cases, the compiler should almost always optimize this assignment away and treat it as it were a temporary only (not a variable). But since I'm not 100% sure, I don't want to put this as an answer. This being said, you should prefer *self-explaining* code over *premature optimization*.

Comment: Yes but, this comes up a lot, especially with `Vector` types that are passed in as temporaries.  I'd rather have a best practice _habit_ than a sub-optimal, marginally more readable standard

Comment: If you want a habit, pass such vectors as const references.

Comment: Ah, the reason it isn't a `const` reference is so that it can be modified in the function body without hurting the original, ie where `situation 1` is the practice

Comment: Why are you asking about performance? Write the clearest code, *then* mutate into whatever gross thing you need to make it run fast *according to data*.

Comment: Because I do this _a lot_ with Vectors, and I really want to know whether __overwriting variables is better than creating new ones__

Comment: So in general is it better to overwrite the variable or to create a new one?

Comment: We have to consider what the operators do don't we? ie. How do we know `operator+` doesn't create a new JelloType and return it? And How do we know whether `operator=` doesn't perform a deep copy of the RHS reference?

Comment: if it's a large object, reusing is likely to be better than creating multiple, because of the memory savings.

Comment: @Porkbutts There's nothing you can do about extra memory used behind the scenes, but you can avoid creating extra variables that you do have control over. At worst, it will be break even.

Comment: @bobobobo: If you're worry is about vectors, you should ask your question with vectors. In general it's better to create a new one because of code clarity: `auto jelloWithTime = jello + time;`.

Comment: @bobobobo It's fairly rare for vector types to come in as arguments.  The usual convention is to pass class types by const reference, not by value.

Comment: If JelloType is a class, the answer depends on the code in the ctor and assignment operator methods.

Comment: If JelloType includes a vector, then passing not by-reference means copying the vector which is usually very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be enhanced with better coding style by removing the temporary object and pass time to `jiggles` function, also rename `jiggles` to `IsJiglly` as it returns bool. Also a const reference should be enough instead of object copy(maybe compiler will optimize away the copy?):

```
bool IsJiggly(const JelloType& jello, float time )
{
   return jello.IsJiggly(time);
}
```

At least this function is identical to both of your function can gather better performance if compiler doesn't elide the copy. Also it's better function design, more intuitive and easier to maintain.

***In C++, is it better, performance wise, to overwrite the variable, or just create a new one and use that?***

This isn't really a language wise issue, it depends on the application design. If JeloType is tiny object which is very cheap to copy(cheaper than copy the reference), then I may won't care making a copy of it.

Comment: I like the coding standard provided by Google. If it's an input param, make it a `const reference`. If it's an output param (or can possibly be modified) make it a pointer. This makes the method signature at least somewhat more explicit to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will probably optimize the difference away in nearly all cases.

Note that simply calling your function causes `jello` to be copied.  If copying a `JelloType` is cheap, then there's no issue.  If it's expensive, then you should probably pass a const reference to it instead.

In your second example, where you introduce the `jello2` temporary, you--in theory--invoke another copy constructor.  If this has side effects, then the compiler won't be able to optimize it away.  If it doesn't have side effect (a good copy constructor should *not* have side effects), then the compiler can probably eliminate the temporary (as your `jello` argument is already a temporary copy).

Sometimes, it makes sense to make a copy, for example, if the name of the copy helps with understanding.  If the copy doesn't make the code easier to understand, and if you've already made a temporary copy because you passed in a copy rather than a reference, then I probably wouldn't introduce `jello2`.

Comment: "In your second example, ... you ... invoke another copy constructor."

How does her first example not invoke the copy constructor? The only difference is whether the copy is stored to a local variable or an already used variable.

Comment: @Porkbutts: Hmm. I may have exaggerated the difference between the examples.  Both involve a copy constructor to pass the parameter.  The first example then uses an assignment operator, while the second uses a copy constructor.  Those may be about equivalent.  But not that it's very common for both of them to be optimized away through, e.g., NRVO.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to say no no sir.

The whole idea of C++ over C and of C over plain machine code is to give some human understandable “meaning” to the code and for the compiler to be able to enforce design decisions (function visibility etc.).  Specifically with C++, it allows you to group variables and functions into “Objects” that you can relate to the real problem object. Optimization shall be the last thing in your head, if at all. Your project will more likely fail from the construction difficulty, bugs and un-maintainability than raw performance.

Sooooo….

1)  If jello was a simple counter, then sure, you don’t need to save the old value. We all know that it increments in time, we all know what the + will do, and we all will be careful when using it. I just will recommend to call it jelloTime, or whatever.

2)  If jello is an object then NOOO:

Jello shall be an entity related to a “real” business object so:

a)  + shall NOT be used to add time or whatever. There is no way for anyone to know that, and jello + time makes no sense to me. (My team knows is not a valid answer). Add a method called  .addFrozentTime() or what ever. ( Avoid addTime(), still not clear … ).

b)  Also, jello refers to some jello eternally as an entity, so a method shall never change the identity of the object, just its state. (The flyweight is an exception, but thats not the point here) So either:

B1) Your comment is wrong:

// I don't need the unrefrigerated jello

Its the same object in different state.  Say “the jello is now refrigerated” and keep the variable…

Or

B2) the code is wrong:

jello = jello + time

- creates a different jello, then of course never reuse the old variable for the new object! Some one later will come and will not be able to tell and just call jello,xxx on the wrong object.

So, the answer is “it depends” but either way you need to revise the code.

My 2 cts I just mean to help.